# UIPickerView selection updates NSArray of UITextFields

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray, uipickerview

I have created a `UIScrollView` that contains a dynamic number of UIViews. Inside each UIView will be a dynamic number of `UItextField`s.

The view itself looks like this

[image]

This white boxes are the UIViews and the black boxes are the `UITextfield`s.

I have a method that puts these `UITextfield`s into an array of arrays. So you have an array of `UIView`s then in each array there is an array of `UITextfield`s.

that code looks like this.

```
for(int i = 0; i< viewcount; i++) {
        color = color + 20;
        NSLog(@"%f", color);
        CGFloat y = i * 91;

        UIScrollView *axisContainerScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, y,self.view.frame.size.width, 90.0)];
        axisContainerScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(600.0, 90.0);
        axisContainerScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [htmlContainerScrollView addSubview:axisContainerScrollView];

//        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, y,self.view.frame.size.width, 90.0)];
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 640.0, 90.0)];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:0/255.0 blue:0/255.0 alpha:(1.0/i)];;
        [axisContainerScrollView addSubview:view];

        int cutCount = [cutsString integerValue];
        int positions = (view.frame.size.width/cutCount);

        for (int i = 0; i < cutCount; i++) {
            //first one
            UITextField *cutField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(((positions*i)-(20/2)+(positions/2)), 25, 20, 20)];
            cutField.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/256.0 green:84/256.0 blue:129/256.0 alpha:1.0];
            cutField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:25];
            cutField.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
            [view addSubview:cutField];

            [columnArrayOfTextFields addObject:cutField]; // array of textfields
        }
        [rowArrayOfTextFields addObject:columnArrayOfTextFields]; // array of arrays

    }
```

What I would like help with is how to then step through each `UITextField` and enter a value from a `UIPickerView`. so as you select values you populate each `UITextField` from left to right and progress downwards through each `UItextField`.

I have a gesture recognizer for the `UIPickerView` where it calles a method like this

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pickerTap:)];
```

I think the `NSArray` of NSArrays is a good start but I'm just not sure how to progress from here.

Comment: A UICollectionView might be a better way to handle this, since it's set up to manage rows/columns/grids of objects.

Comment: okay I will look into this tahnks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use the `tag` property of the `UIView`

What I usually do (since I've come to this problem myself) is :

`A`. You have a known number of elements and you assign the tags from `1` to `n`

`B`. If you can add/delete/or you just have a dynamic number of elements, multiply prime numbers with `1`, `2`, `3` etc.

- For example, on line `1` you use prime number `3`. So your text fields
  will have tags like `3`, `6`, `9`, `12`, `15` and `18`
- Then for second line you will use `7`. So you will have your text field
  tagged with `7`, `14`, `21`, `28`, `35` and `43`
- For line `3` you use `11`
- For line `4` you use `13` and so on ...

There's a lot of way it can be done, these are just on top of my head or actually what I use, if I haven't understood correctly what you want, feel free to let me know.

Comment: okay this definatly makes sense. I will have a go at playing round with it. I have looked for a tag property on UITextField because I have used the UIButton tag but I Havent seen the UITextField version of it.. will check it out again now.

Comment: I have done this but I am not sure how to get the value selected in the UIPickerView into a UITextField.

Comment: can you explain a bit more ? What are you trying to do now ?

Comment: I have a UIPickerView when touched is sends the current value to the pickers delegate method. I would like to know how to get this value into the UITextField. been battling at this all day lol

Comment: that's simple. in didSelectRow, you send the value to the associated UITextField